# Set user based on their attachment to a product

Tags: users, plugin-craftcommerce

With Craft Commerce, I have a custom field that allows you to select which user from a defined group the product belongs to/is associated with.

I want to be able to set the user in order to access additional information about this user (profile info etc) and display this on the relevant product page.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% set user = product.usersFieldHandle.first() %}` will give you the `UserModel` of the first related user.

Then e.g. `{{ user.fieldHandle }}`

Comment: With Craft it usually is :)